# Download thousands of urls

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm developing some service which has to enter my client website and process it's content. As you probably understand, my service is downloading thousands of URLs every hour. Some of those URLs are from same domain.

In order to make the process faster, my application contains 100 threads. Every thread downloading one URL and process it's content.

I'm noticed that after some time of downloading webpages, my "WebRequest.GetResponse()" are stuck. After timeout period, the WebRequest throws Timeout-Exceptions (from all the threads that doing same work). URLs are valid and downloadable (checked).

Ok, so i'm suspected that the server is felling that robot doing this work and stop response to it's requests.

One solution for this situation is to use TOR system. This will makes the requested web-server fell likes it's another client that request for information. The bad side is TOR IPs are public and some servers are blocking those IPs. Therefor, for those specific server the solution won't work.

I'm looking for better solution, someone?

Comment: Don't crawl that server or better yet, ask this server's admin for allowance first?

Comment: So you suspect that the owner of the website doesn't want you to download his data and you ask for ways to circumvent that?

Comment: Absolutely no! The owner of the site allows me to do this job. The server it self has mechanism to protect the server from flooding. This mechanism works automatically in the server. I'm don't want the owner of the site to make any change on his server. Because, in most of time - he wont know how to do this.

Comment: Then work with the admin and get your client authorized to download as much as you need. Going through proxies will only pose new problems.

Comment: It's possible without any change in the server. Check out about google-bot.

Comment: So stop making so many requests at one time? Downloading on 100 threads is unlikely to speed up the process, unless you have *a lot* of bandwidth you can take advantage of.

Answer (score 0):

If you have permission from the site owner ask him to add your IP to the firewall / DDoS protection.

If he has set this functionality up he should be able to add an IP to the allow list